# C++ program crash with no error message only when using a particular library of ArrayFire

Tags: c++, visual-studio, arrayfire

I am trying to use [the ArrayFire library](https://github.com/arrayfire/arrayfire), everything is working perfectly (see the working example above), but I have a problem only when using a particular library `af.lib`. The problem is that when my program crashes, I have no message error and the compilation didn't send back any message either.

### Reproducible Code and/or Steps (working)

1. Add `$(AF_PATH)/include;` to *Project Properties* -> *C/C++* -> *General* -> *Additional Include Directories*.
2. Add `$(AF_PATH)/lib;` to *Project Properties* -> *Linker* -> *General* -> *Additional Library Directories*.
3. Add `afcpu.lib;` to *Project Properties* -> *Linker* -> *Input* -> *Additional Dependencies*.

Here is the code used:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <arrayfire.h>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Main running..." << std::endl;
    
    std::cout << "Available backends: " << af::getAvailableBackends() << std::endl;

   for (int i = 0; i <  af::getDeviceCount();  i++) {
        af::setDevice(i);
        af::info();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Main running...
Available backends: 1
ArrayFire v3.8.2 (CPU, 64-bit Windows, build 5752f2dc)
[0] Intel: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3337U CPU @ 1.80 GHz
```

### Reproducible Code and/or Steps (not working)

1. Add `$(AF_PATH)/include;` to *Project Properties* -> *C/C++* -> *General* -> *Additional Include Directories*.
2. Add `$(AF_PATH)/lib;` to *Project Properties* -> *Linker* -> *General* -> *Additional Library Directories*.
3. Add `af.lib;` to *Project Properties* -> *Linker* -> *Input* -> *Additional Dependencies*.

Here is the code used:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <arrayfire.h>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Main running..." << std::endl;

    try
    {
        std::cout << "Available backends: " << af::getAvailableBackends() << std::endl;
    }
    catch (af::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << "Caught exception trying reading backends" << std::endl;
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

    af::setBackend(AF_BACKEND_CPU);
    for (int i = 0; i <  af::getDeviceCount();  i++) {
        af::setDevice(i);
        af::info();
    }

    af::setBackend(AF_BACKEND_CUDA);
    for (int i = 0; i <  af::getDeviceCount();  i++) {
        af::setDevice(i);
        af::info();
    }

    af::setBackend(AF_BACKEND_OPENCL);
    for (int i = 0; i <  af::getDeviceCount();  i++) {
        af::setDevice(i);
        af::info();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
Main running...
```

If I am running it with the Visual Studio Debugger, here is the error I obtain:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF90AEA4FD9 (KernelBase.dll) in main.exe : 0xC06D007F: Procedure not found (parameters : 0x000000D5546FD0F0).
```

Enabling the Microsoft or the NuGet Symbol Servers doesn't solve the error.

### System Information

Windows 10 64 bits - Intel Core i5-3337U @ 1.80 GHz - Visual Studio Community 2019 16.11.11 - ArrayFire 3.8.2 (CUDA 11.4)

Visual Studio Configuration: Release, x64

Comment: Could you please upload the library you use to Github and share it here if it's convenient for you? and what project did you create.

Comment: Sure, I've added the GitHub at the beginning of my post. For the moment I am just trying to use it for experimentation, but at the end the objective is to make a parallelized ray tracing engine.

Comment: "0xC06D007F: Procedure not found" could mean that there is a program or DLL that was built on one platform (or against one set of DLL dependencies) and is deployed on another platform (or with another set of DLL dependencies).

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a Lib folder in the link you shared, so I can't add the library to the project.